# Mass moment of inertia for the following bodies

Tags: rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, moment-of-inertia

Can you tell the formulas for the mass moment of inertia of a solid cylinder and a solid sphere about their end axis by their height? [Picture 1 & 2]
Derivation isn't necessarily needed right now just the formulas would do.

[image: A solid cylinder and a solid sphere spinning about their end axis by their height]

Comment: Try looking up the moment of inertia for the cylinder and sphere about an axis through the middle and then use the 'parallel axis theorem'

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [parallel axis theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_axis_theorem). The moment of inertia about a sphere or cylinder about their center axes are well known:
$$I_{\mathrm{sphere, center}} = \frac{2}{5} m R^2, \ \ I_{\mathrm{cyl, center}} = \frac{1}{2} m R^2. $$
By the parallel axis theorem, the required moments of inertia about the axes shown are
$$ I_{\mathrm{sphere, side}} = \frac{7}{5} m R^2, \ \ I_{\mathrm{cyl, side}} = \frac{3}{2} m R^2 . $$